# Docker desktop app hangs "Docker Desktop starting..."

Tags: 20.04, gui, docker

I've just installed `docker desktop` app for Debian. When I run it, the gui starts but it hangs with "Docker Desktop starting..." message.

Do you know what to do?

I didn't find a command with which I can run this program from terminal to see the errors.
[image]